# listitemcollection jsonconvert serializeObject fails

Tags: c#, json.net

I tried to use the `NewtonSoft JsonConvert` to convert a `ListItemCollection` in a `Web Service`.

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string TestNewtonSoft()
    {

        System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection coll = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection();

        coll.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("item one", "1"));
        coll.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("item two", "2"));
        coll.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("item three", "3"));
        coll.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("item four", "4"));
        coll.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("item five", "5"));

        string aList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(coll);
        return aList;

    }
```

The result set is

```
["item one","item two","item three","item four","item five"]
```

Text is included, Value is lost.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know why this is happening :).

Its because the list is an `IEnumerable` untyped.
This means that when Json.Net loops throught the items it just gets a list of objects, and when it serializes an object it will use the `ToString()` method which will return the `Text` of the `ListItem`.

Hope that makes things clearer.

You can write a `JsonConverter` to handle the serializtion.
This should give you more or less what you want.

```
public class Json_34159840
{        
    public static void CollectionFails()
    {
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new ListItemConverter() }
        };

        var coll = new ListItemCollection();

        coll.Add(new ListItem("item one", "1"));
        coll.Add(new ListItem("item two", "2"));
        coll.Add(new ListItem("item three", "3"));
        coll.Add(new ListItem("item four", "4"));
        coll.Add(new ListItem("item five", "5"));

        var aList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(coll);
        Console.WriteLine(aList);
    }
}

public class ListItemConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var item = (ListItem)value;

        writer.WriteStartObject();

        writer.WritePropertyName("Text");
        writer.WriteValue(item.Text);

        writer.WritePropertyName("Value");
        writer.WriteValue(item.Value);

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (ListItem);
    }
}
```

This will output

```
[
 {"Text":"item one","Value":"1"},
 {"Text":"item two","Value":"2"},
 {"Text":"item three","Value":"3"},
 {"Text":"item four","Value":"4"},
 {"Text":"item five","Value":"5"}
]
```

Note that I haven't done the deserialization.

Comment: I actually ended up converting the collection into a List<String, String>.  I guess my question and my surprised why it does not work out of the box when I have no problem serializing much more complex items.